# When you use Chancellor to discard your deck, do you gain a gold for each Tunnel discarded?

Tags: dominion, dominion-hinterlands

When you play [Chancellor](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=chancellor) and choose to move your discard pile into your deck, do you gain a Gold for each [Tunnel](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=tunnel) moved into your discard pile?

From the wording of Chancellor, I would assume no because it doesn't mention that you're discarding those cards, but I don't have access to the rules at the moment to see if either base or Hinterlands rules cover this.

Comment: If you're interested in setting up a mass-Tunnel chain, consider using a Golem, which can discard the entire deck AND discard pile with sufficiently few non-Golem action cards in your deck.

Comment: @Johno: Hmm, that makes me wonder what other cards are worded that way.  In theory, for a low-money deck, Adventurer may work.  However, starting with 7 Coppers makes this one harder to pull off.

Comment: Adventurer would also work, but is a little tougher, as you say. Another good tactic is using cards that discard your hand when your hand is full of Tunnels. For instance, Scouts can pull Tunnels from your deck if they're nearby, then a well-placed Minion or Tactician can cash them all in. I once played a Tactician on a post-Tactician 10-card hand because it had three or four Tunnels in it!

Comment: @Johno: Of course, [Cartographer](http://dominion.diehrstraits.com/?card=cartographer) is better at it, as you can discard them directly (plus you draw one card first).  Then again, that's why Cartographer costs 5 instead of 4.

Comment: Absolutely, Cartographer's a great Tunnel partner (which I totally forgot about :P)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

Per the [Hinterland Rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_396_gameRules.pdf), Chancellor does not trigger Tunnel

> This ability does not function if cards are put into your discard pile without being discarded, .... when your deck is put into your discard pile, such as with Chancellor

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Per [Dominion base Rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_278_gameRules.pdf):

> "Discard" – unless otherwise specified, discarded cards are **from the player’s
>   hand**. When a player discards a card, he places the discarded card face-up
>   onto his Discard pile. When discarding several cards at once, the player
>   need not show all cards he is discarding to his opponents, but player may
>   need to show how many cards he is discarding (for example, when
>   playing the Cellar). The top card of a player’s Discard pile is always visible

So, you are not *discarding* the Tunnels in your deck when you activate the Chancellor: you are simply moving them in the Discard pile.

Comment: Just to clear any possible confusion, it is possible to discard cards from your deck instead of from your hand. Spy is one of many cards that can do this. But Chancellor doesn't discard any cards, it just moves cards into the discard pile.

Comment: Yes, but in that case it explicitly uses the word _discard_ thus falling in the "unless otherwise specified" case of the _discard_ definition. Anyway, good point in making it clearer.